# Visual studio 2017 go to implementation not work for .net standard library

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard-2.0

In Visual studio 2017, Go to Implementation for .net standard library not work?
Go to Implementation for .net core library work fine. but for .net standard throw

> The symbol has no implementations

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what are you using F12 on? is it a .net project?

Comment: @Neville Nazerane, F12 go to interface, I use Ctrl+F12 for go to Implementation but not work. project is .net core console application

Comment: is this a built-in interface or your own interface?

Comment: this is my defined interface

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am having the same issue after upgrading to .Net core 2.1. As work around I use

> F12 then Ctrl+F12 from the Interface

Update: Seems like it is VS issue and there is no plan to be resolved soon

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/111096/f12-go-to-definition-does-not-work-in-net-standard.html

Comment: This not work for me by conditions that write in question

Comment: @MohammadAkbari Is it your app  .Net core 2.1?

Comment: Yes, Is it .Net core 2.1

Comment: "soon" eheh. still doesn't work :( without that work around.

Answer (score 0):

I found that changing from:

`<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`

to:

`<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp3.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>`

solved the problem.

Comment: Where do you change it? What does it do?

Comment: edit csproj file. that solved problem with navigation to implementation with ctrl+f12

Answer (score 0):

Delete .vs folder usually work. this folder is same place as your solution file
[image]